# Why can't I connect to this IIS FTP?

Tags: iis, ftp

I have a Windows 2003 server where i've configured FTP in IIS.

I'm by no means an expert in FTP configuration, and I don't recall any special settings I could've made.
This worked initially, but at some point it just stopped working, and I can't think of anything that could've changed that could've broken it.

Here is the log that FileZilla is giving me:
(censored to protect the innocent)

```
Status: Resolving address of www.xxxxxx.com
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.12:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER xxxxxxxx
Response:   331 Password required for xxxxxxxx.
Command:    PASS **********
Response:   230 User xxxxxxxx logged in.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/xxxxxxxx" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xxx,xxx,12,4,44).
Command:    LIST
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I've tried setting FileZilla to connect using both Active and Passive mode. Neither works.

I'm not sure what could be going on... I've configured a number of FTP servers in the same way, and they all just work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the FTP server behind a firewall? Is it a NAT firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make sure that's the only thing listening on that port.
- make sure firewall holes are open.
- directory permissions and FTP directory permissions aren't always the same thing. Check both.

Comment: It was the firewall and I feel dumb :-(    I still blame Windows though (probably some Windows Update), since the Firewall has always been up, and this used to work

Answer (score 4):

I have two ideas.  First, have you checked the filesystem permissions to make sure that they user you are logging in with can list the contents of the directory?  Second, have you tried any other FTP programs?  If not, there is a possibility that it is actually a FileZilla problem, not a server problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try testing locally on the computer with windows FTP or whatever FTP program you feel safe running on the server.  That will let you know if the issue is a firewall or network block, or if it's a server configuration issue.

Also, there are FTP logs that will show all connections to the server and failures.  If you go to the properties of the FTP site, it will give the path to the log files.  If you don't see any connections, it's likely a firewall issue.  If you do see entries, check out what type of failure is occurring.